# Firebase getting current user uid

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Does Firebase count the getting current user id or email (`Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid` , `Auth.auth().currentUser?.email`) as a read operation and charge it? I searched the documentation but could not find any information.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Please edit the question to show the code that you're working with, and explain the part of that where the billing is uncertain.

Comment: Ok, added some code.

Comment: OK, this isn't about Firestore at all.  You are only showing code that works with Firebase Authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no charge associated with getting current user id or email or any kind of auth information. Firebase auth is completely free except the phone auth. You can have unlimited number of users in Firebase Authentication with email, Google, Microsoft etc.

The charge with reference to the read operations is for Firestore. It is totally separate 'module' than Authentication.

Answer (score 1):

The code you're showing is just working with Firebase Authentication, which does not have any billing associated at all for its API, except for use of phone authentication.  This should be clear from the [documentation on pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing).